# Jenkins role strategy plugin and restrict user to build if not in proper group -- Jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops

We have two environments, **qa** and **dev**, and that is configured as parameters in Jenkinsfile. Plugin **Role-based Authorization Strategy** is enabled, and there are two groups of users, **qa** and **dev** (same as environment). The problem here is that **qa** users can start to build jobs with **dev** environment. Is there any way that we restrict this behavior?
Here is a simple example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
     
    choice(name: 'environment', choices: ['dev', 'qa']

    stages {    
        stage('test') { 
            script {
              if (params.environment == 'dev' && env.BUILD_USER_ID not in env.BUILD_USER_GROUPS) {echo "User ${env.BUILD_USER_ID} can not start build on DEV enviroment"}
              else if (params.environment == 'qa' && env.BUILD_USER_ID not in env.BUILD_USER_GROUPS) {echo "User ${env.BUILD_USER_ID} can not start build on QA enviroment"}
              else {echo "You can run job, You are in proper group for this enviroment"}
        } 
      }                     
    }
  }
```

An example is not real, and maybe not working, but I hope that can be understood what I want to accomplish.

P.S. Documentation for this is not so good, and also can't find much more examples on web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of blocking (or failing) the execution after it started, you can use a different approach and prevent an unauthorized user to even start the build with irrelevant parameters (dev environment in this case).
To do so you can use the [Extended Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter/) plugin, it enables you to create a select list value (multi or single select) based on the return value of a groovy script.
Then you can use the following script:

```
def buildUserGroup = ["group1","group 2","group3"]
def environments = ['qa']  // This default value will be available to everyone

// All the groups that the current logged in user is a member of
def currentUserGroups = hudson.model.User.current().getAuthorities() 
if (currentUserGroups.any{ buildUserGroup.contains(it) }) {
    environments.add("dev")  // Add relevant environments according to groups
}
return environments
```

This way you can define the logic that will add environments according to group membership and adjusted it according to your needs. The user that builds the job wont even see the environments that he is not allowed to build and you will get the restriction you need.
In a Pipeline Job  using your requirements the configuration can be simplified and will look like:

```
 pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        extendedChoice(name: 'environment', type: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', description: 'Environment type', visibleItemCount: 10,
                groovyScript:"return hudson.model.User.current().getAuthorities().contains('dev') ? ['dev','qa'] : ['qa']")
    }
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
If you are using the Role-based Authorization Strategy and want to use the above solution with roles instead of groups you can use the following code (based on [this script](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/export-role-strategy-permissions-to-csv.groovy) in your parameter:

```
def environments = ['qa']  // This default value will be available to everyone

def userID = hudson.model.User.current().id  // The current user it
def authStrategy = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getAuthorizationStrategy()
def permissions = authStrategy.roleMaps.inject([:]){map, it -> map + it.value.grantedRoles}

// Validate current user is in the 'dev' role
if (permissions.any{it.key.name == 'dev' && it.value.contains(userID)}) {
    environments.add("dev")  // Add relevant environments according to groups
}
return environments
```

Comment: It not working properly. When dev user start job with parameters, it have only qa option

Comment: Noam Helmer Plus, the second code must be inside parameters {}

Comment: @Savke i tested it against our groups and it worked fine. you can go to Manage Jenkins -> Script Console and run `println hudson.model.User.current().getAuthorities()` to see list of all groups and make sure you are suing the right string.  Regarding the `{}` what do you mean? it is a declarative syntax that should reside inside the `parameters` section, i will update the answer to emphasize this.

Comment: running ```println hudson.model.User.current().getAuthorities()``` i get ```[]``` as a result. For second thing, yes yes, I mean that. Tnx for editing

Comment: Is your Jenkins authentication configured with Groups? You can validate it by going to you user profile and see if there is a list of groups you are assigned to. (you must be logged in for that)

Comment: no, its not visible. But it is enabled Role-based Authorization Strategy. Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: Are you trying to use groups or roles? it is quite different...

Comment: I am using roles

Comment: @Savke I updated the answer with a solution for roles